# Should CUDA questions be tagged C and/or C++?

Tags: discussion, tags

CUDA is a GPU programming environment developed by Nvidia.

There are actually two languages in question: one for building code to run on the GPU, and one for building code to run on the CPU. Neither are standard C or standard C++; both are a subset of standard C++.  Neither is a superset of C, but code written in this language strongly resembles what is normally called "C-style" code, i.e. C++ code which mostly uses features from the common subset of C and C++.

Confusingly, Nvidia market the languages as "Cuda C" despite the fact that they are C++ with some features removed. Nvidia say that they are working to gradually increase the amount of standard C++ which is supported.

Typically, people who tag [cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda) sometimes tag [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and sometimes tag [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), and sometimes even both; it'd be more consistent to decide on one option and stick with it.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue in favor of the actual language being used to program, as opposed to the framework.

If they're writing C, it should be tagged as such.  If it's C++, it should be tagged as such.  Don't forget to remind the OP to be explicit about which language they're using, since they're definitely not the same.

Comment: Well - it's neither. It's two languages that both have a strong (but not exact) resemblance to a C-like subset of C++. Nvidia's special compiler is required to compile them.

Comment: Then why bother tagging it at all?  If it isn't C or C++, then it truly is just CUDA, unless there are specific language issues in the question.

Comment: Tagging C or C++ brings in a lot of expert coders who don't know CUDA but can help with the question ; much of the time the issue is something that lies in the common intersection of standard C or C++, and "CUDA C".

Comment: I disagree.  Tag what is relevant to the question.  If I was asking about the Win32 API, it wouldn't make sense to leave that tag out.  If I'm writing Google Script Engine code, you wouldn't want to leave out JavaScript/ECMAScript just because the specs are technically different (while they might as well be the same language).

Comment: @Brad so what is your advice exactly?

Comment: Tags can be updated/corrected after the question is posted and even after it's answered if necessary, @Matt, but they should not be applied just to gain visibility; they're really for categorization.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: You answer yourself: It's neither C nor C++, so both tags would be wrong. Tagging to mislead people into looking at it, irrespective of their ability to help, is bad and a blatant misuse of the system and anyone who stumbles across the question. If "much of the time the issue is something that lies in the intersection of A and B" was a valid reason to tag something "on suspicion", most C# questions could be validly tagged C as well.

Comment: @deduplicator so what is the correct tag?  ("cuda" is a much wider scope than Cuda-C or Cuda-C++)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Might need a CUDA-C or CUDA-C++ tag, or both. I'm not sure.